# Send welcome message in a random channel when invited to guild

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Whenever the bot is invited, I want it to send a message to a channel in the server, similar to what Dank Memer and Members+ used to have. However, I don't want it to pick one channel name, I want it to pick a random channel every time.

```js
bot.on("guildCreate", () => {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(bot.user.username, bot.user.avatarURL)
        .addField(`:wave: Welcome!`, `Thanks for adding Thickets to your server.`)
        .addField(`Getting Started`, `First of all, this bot is still under development and is getting frequent changes. We are looking for developers.`)
        .addField(`Use the command t.help to view all the commands!`)
        .setColor(0x00ff00)
        .setFooter(`Thanks for adding Thickets, I wish you luck!`);
    
    message.channel.send(embed);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the first part correct, you use the `guildCreate` event for when your bot joins a server.

To get a random channel, you would have to get the guild you have joined, `<Client>.on("guildCreate", (guild))`, you can then get the channels with `guild.channels` that will get you to the [GuildChannelManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager).

Now with the way discord.js caching works, you will now need to get into the channel cache, with `guild.channels.cache` and you will then have a collection.

To make sure you are only getting Text Channels and not Voice, Category, etc. You can use filter on the collection `.filter(x => x.type == 'text')`, it will return a new filtered collection.

With the new [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) you can then use `.random(1)` to return 1 random result from the [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection). You will then have a [GuildChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel).

The code to accomplish this would be

```js
bot.on('guildCreate', (guild) => {
guild.channels.cache
    .filter(x => x.type == 'text')
    .random(1)[0]
    .send(embed);
});
```

Comment: So is this right: 

https://www.codepile.net/pile/lkpq8zMD

Comment: actually, i see the problem now. look on line 11, youre closing the event before your code is executed https://i.imgur.com/QBjd6eU.png

Comment: how can i fix that?

Comment: is this good? https://www.codepile.net/pile/4bVrZzbp